# Number of active connections and remaining connections

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I would like to get statistics about the peak number of connections over a period of time.

I know the `pg_stat_activity` view, like `select count(*) from pg_stat_activity`, but I think this method is not very smart.

Are there other views or tables that can provide the information I need?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This SQL will help you

```
select max_conn,used,res_for_super,max_conn-used-res_for_super res_for_normal 
from 
  (select count(*) used from pg_stat_activity) t1,
  (select setting::int res_for_super from pg_settings where name=$$superuser_reserved_connections$$) t2,
  (select setting::int max_conn from pg_settings where name=$$max_connections$$) t3
```

Result:

```
max_conn | used | res_for_super | res_for_normal 
---------+------+---------------+----------------
  100    |    2 |             3 |             95
(1 row)
```

You can put this in shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=1; c<=3600; c++ ))
do
     gsql -U pgdba -W pgdba -p 6432 -c "sql" >> /home/pgdba/res_data.log
     sleep 1  # once per second
done
```

or you can record the results into a table, then execute

```
postgres=# copy restbl to '/home/pgdba/res.csv' csv header;
```

to get result csv file.

Comment: what is res_for_super and res_for_normal means ?

Comment: @DBA100, based on my tests, `res_for_super` means how many connections remain for superuser (`postgres` and others) and `res_for_normal` same but for regular users.